# Postgresql how to select values in the column from one table that are only available in another table?

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgresql and need to query two tables like this:

Table1

```
  ID     Bill  
  A       1
  B       2
  B       3
  C       4
```

Table2

```
 ID  
  A     
  B
```

I want a table with all the columns in Table1 but keeping only the records with IDs that are available in Table2 (A and B in this case). Also, Table2's ID is unique.

```
  ID     Bill  
  A       1
  B       2
  B       3
```

Which join I should use or if I can use WHERE statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1
  INNER JOIN Table2 USING (ID);
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Table2);
```

but the first one is better for performance reason.

Comment: Thanks! Will this one takes less time than the first one? I have run with the first one for 15 minutes now... and the query is still running.

Comment: @JohnSmith: The relevant thing for performance: Indexes. If at least `table2.id` or both IDs are indexed (or primary key which is indexed automatically), your query should be fast. [More in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes.html) or in countless answers here on SO.

Comment: Thanks! But there's no primary keys for these tables. Maybe I will try another way. I don't think the query will end before sunset.

Comment: @JohnSmith: I suspected as much. Create indexes to make this fast.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.ID = Table1.ID LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Why we use LIMIT 1 here?

Comment: @JohnSmith: `LIMIT 1` is of no use in this context.