# SELECT records that have top n counts for one column

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I am using postgresql 9.2.

I have a dataset like this:

```
ID  A   B
1   x   x  
2   x   x 
2   x   x
2   x   x
3   x   x
4   x   x
4   x   x
```

I want to display records with ID that has the top n count.  Say, top 2 counts of ID--in this case, ID=2 and 4. 
So the dataset should be:

```
ID  A  B
2   x  x
2   x  x   
2   x  x
4   x  x
4   x  x
```

My first thought was to create a new view by calculating the top n count, and then match the ID of the new view with the ID of the original table, thanks for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992558/postgresql-how-to-select-values-in-the-column-from-one-table-that-are-only-avail)
However, the query runs forever, since EXISTS takes enormous time.

I wonder if there's a better way to do this?

Comment: `wonder if there's a better way to do this?` Now: what did you do? why is `EXISTS() that bad? show us!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16992558/905902 : complete duplicate.

Comment: @wildplasser: That one doesn't t look like a duplicate to me.

Comment: @wildplasser  I over-simplified the problem here so that not to confuse people. My actual task is to dealing with data of millions of records, that's why EXISTS without creating index will not finish the work at all (I said this clearly in Q). Gordon's answer exactly solved the problem. I didn't know what to do, that's why I came here. Also please read Q carefully before arguing it's a complete duplicate.

Comment: The OQ does not show any effort. There is no schema, no query, only the mentioning of the word EXISTS. The fact that Gordon's query works good for you could be by sheer coincidence, IMHO. If your data would be 10* as big, things would probably be different. And *simplifying things* does not make things simpler, it only confuses people.

Comment: @wildplasser  As long as there are people answered the question, it was not confusing at all. The actual data is 1 million* as big. If it still bothers you, feel free to vote down. I appreciate your time wasted on commenting, but the answers below helped me more.

Comment: Well, as a question what is the relevance of having 1 million records with columns A and B both being 'X' ? If A and B don't matter, why bother to mention them ? If A and B do matter (and 'X' is just a metasyntactical laziness constant) they *could* be (part of) a candidate key (id is not, obviously). But you did not show us. You mentioned `EXISTS`, but you did not show us the query where it was supposed to be part of, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with nested window functions:

```
select t.id, t.a, t.b
from (select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by idcnt desc, id) as seqnum
      from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by id) as idcnt
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

You can check out the [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/988).

Comment: Thanks! I will end my query now (run for 40 minutes already) and try this.

Comment: I just edited it a bit since there are 3 t here, but they have different purpose. The first `t` means the original table, while the other two `t` look like a temporary table name.

Comment: @JohnSmith . . . I just generically use `t` for both tables and aliases when there is no better name to use.  In the innermost query, you could write `from <your table name> t`, and the rest of the query would work.

Answer (score 2):

This should be considerably simpler and faster than two subquery levels with window functions.

```
SELECT *
FROM   t
JOIN  (
   SELECT id
   FROM   t
   GROUP  BY 1
   ORDER  BY count(*) DESC
   LIMIT  2
   ) top2 USING (id)
```

As mentioned before, you need an index for this to be really fast. If `id` is your primary key you are all set.